# nuxt3 build not working got some error in nuxt-icon

Tags: nuxt.js, nuxtjs3

my project work correctly when i run `yarn dev` icons and everything work, but when i use `yarn build` i got error

```
ERROR  [vite:vue] Could not load C:/myPath/nuxt 3/\u200F\u200Faliexpress-tailwind/node_modules/nuxt-icon/dist/runtime/Icon.vue?vue&type=style&index=0&scoped=9c34c54e&lang.css?inline&used: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:/myPath/nuxt 3/\u200F\u200Faliexpress-tailwind/node_modules/nuxt-icon/dist/runtime/Icon.vue'
```

node v: v18.16.0
nuxt: 3.5.2
nuxt-icon: 0.5.0

i use also @vite-pwa/nuxt v: 0.1.0

im trying to update nuxt-icon but still not work..

Comment: Hi, can you please provide a [repro]?